# PHP update database mysqli form

Tags: php, database, forms, mysqli, html-table

I am currently trying to write a system where I can add editable fields from the database onto a webpage then submit the information and change the data that's in the database.

I have got the data to be shown in the text fields but I cannot seem to get the update function to work...

```
<?php $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'adwawdaw', 'awdawdaw', 'awdawdaw'); 
     $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM information WHERE id = 1');
        if (is_object($result)) {
            if ($result->num_rows) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $banner = $row['banner'];
                    $embed = $row['embed'];
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $date = $row['date'];
                    $time = $row['time'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                    $region = $row['region'];
                    $sponsors = $row['sponsors'];
                }
            }
        }
    ?>

<form method="post" action="edit1.php">
<table>
<br />
<tr>
<td>Banner: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="banner" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($banner) ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Embed: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="embed" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($embed) ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Event Title: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($title) ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date) ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Time: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="time" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($time) ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description) ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Region: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="region" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($region) ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sponsors: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="sponsors" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sponsors) ?>"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Update!">
</form>
<?php 
$banner = $_POST['banner'];
$embed = $row['embed'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$date = $row['date'];
$time = $row['time'];
$description = $row['description'];
$region = $row['region'];
$sponsors = $row['sponsors'];

$mysqli->query('UPDATE livestreamadmin SET title = $title WHERE id=1');
    ?>
```

Comment: Is the code at the bottom of the page not right?

Comment: `SET title =$title` that's failing if it's a string and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php on your query would have signaled it. It needs to be quoted.

Comment: ...as in `SET title = '$title'` and you should be good to go.

Comment: you also need to use a conditional statement around your POST arrays too, since you're using your entire code in the same file. Seems like it.

Comment: unfortunately that just sends the page white.

Comment: white page means errors. So use error reporting and error checking on the query.

Comment: You have to use double quotes too: `$mysqli->query("UPDATE livestreamadmin SET title = '$title' WHERE id=1");`